# setting list element names based on argument to `pmap`

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to figure out if I can use the `list` of arguments provided to `purrr::pmap()` to also name the elements of the **output list** from this function using `purrr::set_names()`.

For example, here is a simple example where I am using `pmap` to create summary for some variables from different dataframes across grouping variables.

```r
# setup
library(tidyverse)
library(groupedstats)
set.seed(123)

# creating the dataframes
data_1 <- tibble::as.tibble(iris)
data_2 <- tibble::as.tibble(mtcars)
data_3 <- tibble::as.tibble(airquality)

# creating a list
purrr::pmap(
  .l = list(
    data = list(data_1, data_2, data_3),
    grouping.vars = alist(Species, c(am, cyl), Month),
    measures = alist(c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width), wt, c(Ozone, Solar.R, Wind))
  ),
  .f = groupedstats::grouped_summary
) %>% # assigning names to each element of the list
  purrr::set_names(x = ., nm = alist(data_1, data_2, data_3))

# output
#> $data_1
#> # A tibble: 6 x 16
#>   Species type  variable missing complete     n  mean    sd   min   p25
#>   <fct>   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 setosa  nume~ Sepal.L~       0       50    50  5.01  0.35   4.3  4.8 
#> 2 setosa  nume~ Sepal.W~       0       50    50  3.43  0.38   2.3  3.2 
#> 3 versic~ nume~ Sepal.L~       0       50    50  5.94  0.52   4.9  5.6 
#> 4 versic~ nume~ Sepal.W~       0       50    50  2.77  0.31   2    2.52
#> 5 virgin~ nume~ Sepal.L~       0       50    50  6.59  0.64   4.9  6.23
#> 6 virgin~ nume~ Sepal.W~       0       50    50  2.97  0.32   2.2  2.8 
#> # ... with 6 more variables: median <dbl>, p75 <dbl>, max <dbl>,
#> #   std.error <dbl>, mean.low.conf <dbl>, mean.high.conf <dbl>
#> 
#> $data_2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 17
#>      am   cyl type  variable missing complete     n  mean    sd   min   p25
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     6 nume~ wt             0        3     3  2.75  0.13  2.62  2.7 
#> 2     1     4 nume~ wt             0        8     8  2.04  0.41  1.51  1.78
#> 3     0     6 nume~ wt             0        4     4  3.39  0.12  3.21  3.38
#> 4     0     8 nume~ wt             0       12    12  4.1   0.77  3.44  3.56
#> 5     0     4 nume~ wt             0        3     3  2.94  0.41  2.46  2.81
#> 6     1     8 nume~ wt             0        2     2  3.37  0.28  3.17  3.27
#> # ... with 6 more variables: median <dbl>, p75 <dbl>, max <dbl>,
#> #   std.error <dbl>, mean.low.conf <dbl>, mean.high.conf <dbl>
#> 
#> $data_3
#> # A tibble: 15 x 16
#>    Month type  variable missing complete     n   mean     sd   min    p25
#>    <int> <chr> <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     5 inte~ Ozone          5       26    31  23.6   22.2    1    11   
#>  2     5 inte~ Solar.R        4       27    31 181.   115.     8    72   
#>  3     5 nume~ Wind           0       31    31  11.6    3.53   5.7   8.9 
#>  4     6 inte~ Ozone         21        9    30  29.4   18.2   12    20   
#>  5     6 inte~ Solar.R        0       30    30 190.    92.9   31   127   
#>  6     6 nume~ Wind           0       30    30  10.3    3.77   1.7   8   
#>  7     7 inte~ Ozone          5       26    31  59.1   31.6    7    36.2 
#>  8     7 inte~ Solar.R        0       31    31 216.    80.6    7   175   
#>  9     7 nume~ Wind           0       31    31   8.94   3.04   4.1   6.9 
#> 10     8 inte~ Ozone          5       26    31  60.0   39.7    9    28.8 
#> 11     8 inte~ Solar.R        3       28    31 172.    76.8   24   107   
#> 12     8 nume~ Wind           0       31    31   8.79   3.23   2.3   6.6 
#> 13     9 inte~ Ozone          1       29    30  31.4   24.1    7    16   
#> 14     9 inte~ Solar.R        0       30    30 167.    79.1   14   117.  
#> 15     9 nume~ Wind           0       30    30  10.2    3.46   2.8   7.55
#> # ... with 6 more variables: median <dbl>, p75 <dbl>, max <dbl>,
#> #   std.error <dbl>, mean.low.conf <dbl>, mean.high.conf <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

As can be seen here, the contents of `data` argument to `purrr::pmap` and `nm` argument in `purrr::set_names` are exactly identical (`(data_1, data_2, data_3)`). I want to **avoid this repetition** (which seems unnecessary here with `3` elements, but I have a much bigger list of arguments). I can't assign this list to a separate object because in one case it is a `list`, while the other one is entered as `alist`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `tidyverse` package, you can also use `lst` function. `lst` is used for creating list. It is like `tibble` function to create tibble but for creating list. One of the difference with base `list()` is that it automatically names the list.
It is in dplyr, exported from tibble.

For the example, I also replace base `alist` by `rlang::exprs` as it is [equivalent](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quotation.html#capture-raw-expressions). Indeed, both are ok.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(groupedstats)
set.seed(123)

# creating the dataframes
data_1 <- tibble::as.tibble(iris)
data_2 <- tibble::as.tibble(mtcars)
data_3 <- tibble::as.tibble(airquality)

# creating a list
purrr::pmap(
  .l = list(
    data = lst(data_1, data_2, data_3),
    grouping.vars = rlang::exprs(Species, c(am, cyl), Month),
    measures = rlang::exprs(c(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width), wt, c(Ozone, Solar.R, Wind))
  ),
  .f = groupedstats::grouped_summary
) %>%
  str(1)
#> List of 3
#>  $ data_1:Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  16 variables:
#>  $ data_2:Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':  6 obs. of  17 variables:
#>  $ data_3:Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame':  15 obs. of  16 variables:
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>